# Adminstering GoDady using CLI/API

Tags: command-line, dns, domain, capistrano

Is there any tool CLI/API where one can automate the GoDady DNS related operations such as addind/removing DNS records and managing SSL certificates and domain names?  without wasting time around on doing too many clicks.

Comment: have you looked at [the GoDaddy developer API documentation?](https://developer.godaddy.com/doc)

Comment: That seems to be a live API ,  is there any implementation of that in some language like python or go ?

Comment: You could just use `curl` from the CLI to use their API.  Apparently there are bindings for many different languages.  You should search for your most desired implementation.

Comment: I have been searching alot , I have found only one , for adding /removing dns records.

Answer (score 0):

There is the official [GoDaddy API Python binding](https://github.com/godaddy/gdapi-python) which should also be available on [PyPI.org](https://pypi.org/project/gdapi-python/) and have all the GoDaddy APIs available.

I found a few unofficial bindings for `python`, you can see them with `pip search godaddy`.

I have never used any of them so I have no idea how good they are.

Comment: The python one only deals with dns records

Comment: unfortunately the official python bindings repo has been archived

Comment: this could be an alternative https://github.com/eXamadeus/godaddypy

Answer (score 0):

I think that [daddy](https://github.com/artberri/daddy) may be what your are looking for.  Once you have configured your API key, you can run *daddy* from the command line to add, list, show, remove, or update DNS records.  I have only used the linux version of *daddy*, but Windows and even "darwin" versions are provided at [the release site](https://github.com/artberri/daddy/releases).